# Why can't streaming connect to the Java socket client?

Tags: apache-spark

I am studying Spark streaming to process real time data, and I built the example wordCount of spark streaming, and I can run the example after:

```
/bin/run-example org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.JavaNetworkWordCount local[2] localhost 9999
```

And if I run `nc -L -p 9999` in another terminal, then I can type letters in this terminal, and the example can receive the letters and give the right result.

But I developed a Java socket client to send content to 9999 port - why can't the example receive it? I think the example just monitor the 9999 port, and receive anything from the port.

Here is the Java code:

```
    File file = new File("D:\\OutputJson.dat");
    long l = file.length();
    socket = new Socket();
    boolean connected = false;
    while (!connected) {
        //not stop until send successful
        try {
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9999));
            connected = true;
            System.out.println("connected success!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("connected failed!");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
    dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    sendBytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((length = fis.read(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.length)) > 0) {
        sumL += length;
        System.out.println("sent:" + ((sumL / l) * 100) + "%");
        dos.write(sendBytes, 0, length);
        dos.flush();
    }
    if (sumL == l) {
        bool = true;
    }
```

This Java function is always returning the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
```

I have developed another Java class to receive the data from this sending socket, and it works fine, why the can't spark receive with this one?

Comment: The JavaNetworkWordCount assumes that the records are separated by \n. If your data in OutputJson.data is not separated by \n then the spark streaming receiver wont find the end of the record, and so not receive anything correctly.

Answer (score -1):

From memory I think I used a ServerSocket.  The code was something like:

```
public void sendMsg(String msg) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.write(msg);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } finally {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } finally {
            clientSocket = null;
            serverSocket = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem cannot be solved this way, because spark cannot write from executors